# Trying to Iterate through "Fetch" JSON Data after assigning to State in React.js for a "Slider" component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

pretty new to React so don't clown me to hard haha.

Essentially my goal is to fetch the data from my personal JSON server & render that data onto a "Slider" that I am creating.

I am following along with a tutorial and decided to give myself a challenge, the only difference is that where he just imported a data.js file with his data, I wanted to use JSON data / server instead.

The issues is that I'm not sure how to ".map()" through the data for each slide and render to the slider. I have a general idea of how but I'm not fully sure how to implement it correctly in the context of using JSON data with fetch requests.

I have fetched my JSON url and used .thens to string my responses & assign the data to a state setter function. When I console.log the data I receive the object successfully but twice.

Read online that I could use the first variable of state to .map(), attempted and has not worked.

Sorry if this has been touched on before, I have tried everything to find this info before asking but to no avail.

The error I receive is in regards to me using the state variable "slideIndx.map" not being a function.

What can I do here?

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { ArrowLeftOutlined, ArrowRightOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";

import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 95vh;
    display: flex;
    // background-color: #b3f0ff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
`;
const Arrow = styled.div`
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #e6ffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: ${props => props.direction === "left" && "10px"};
    right: ${props => props.direction === "right" && "10px"};
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 2;
`;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    transform: translateX(0vw)
`
const Slide = styled.div`
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: ${props => props.bg};
`
const ImgContainer = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    flex:1;
`
const Image = styled.img`
    padding-left: 30px;
    align-items: left;
`
const InfoContainer = styled.div`
    height: 80%;
    flex:1;
    padding: 30px;
`
const Title = styled.h1`
    font-size: 50px
`
const Desc = styled.p`
    margin: 50px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
`
const Button = styled.button`
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
`


const Slider = () => {
    const [slideIndx, setSlideIndx] = useState(0);

    const fetchSliderItems = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/sliderItems')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            setSlideIndx(data)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {fetchSliderItems()}, [])


    const handleClick = (direction) => {}

  return (
    <Container>
        <Arrow direction="left" onClick={() => handleClick("left")}>
            <ArrowLeftOutlined />
        </Arrow>
        // Here is where I am attempting to map over the items.
        <Wrapper>
        {fetchSliderItems.map((item) => (
            <Slide bg={item.bg}>
            <ImgContainer>
                <Image src={item.img}/>
            </ImgContainer>
            <InfoContainer>
                <Title>{item.title}</Title>
                <Desc>{item.desc}</Desc>
                <Button>SHOP NOW</Button>
            </InfoContainer>
            </Slide>
        ))}
        </Wrapper>

        <Arrow direction="right" onClick={() => handleClick("right")}>
            <ArrowRightOutlined />
        </Arrow>

    </Container>
  )
}

export default Slider
```

```html
{
  "sliderItems": [

    {
        "id": 1,
        "img": "../images/model1.png",
        "title": "SPRING CLEANING",
        "desc": "DONT MISS OUR BEST COLLECTION YET! USE #FLATIRON10 TO RECEIVE 10% OFF YOUR FIRST ORDER",
        "bg": "b3ecff"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "img": "https://i.ibb.co/DG69bQ4/2.png",
        "title": "SHOW OFF HOW YOU DRESS",
        "desc": "WITH OUR HUGE SELECTION OF CLOTHES WE FIT ALL YOUR STYLING NEEDS",
        "bg": "ccf2ff"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "img": "../images/model1.png",
        "title": "POPULAR DEALS",
        "desc": "RECEIVE FREE SHIPPING ON ALL ORDERS OVER $50!",
        "bg": "fe6f9ff"
      }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should share the error you're getting. But based on the second screenshot, it looks like your array is wrapped in a `sliderItems` object.

You want a raw array when you `.map`. So maybe try setting your `slideIndx` to the raw array by doing something like:

```js
setSlideIndx(data.sliderItems)
```

Try confirming the shape of your state by console logging above your `return` with:

```
console.log(slideIndx)
```

Comment: Slider.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: fetchSliderItems.map is not a function
    at Slider (Slider.js:97:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16141:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20838:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22342:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4157:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4206:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4270:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27243:1)

Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You're calling map from `fetchSliderItems.map`, but `fetchSliderItems` is a function, not an array. You need to call map from the array containing the data, which in your case is `slideIndx.sliderItems`.

What happens in your code is `const [slideIndx, setSlideIndx] = useState(0);` initializes `slideIndx` to `0`. When `useEffect` runs `fetchSliderItems`, you'll fetch the data and eventually the line `setSlideIndx(data)` assigns `data` to `slideIndx`. Because your data is an object that holds and array in the `sliderItems` property, the array can now be accessed in `slideIndx.sliderItems`.

So fist thing you should do to fix it is change the `useState` line to `const [slideIndx, setSlideIndx] = useState([]);`, because you want your state variable to be an array. Then when you fetch the data you want to call `setSlideIndx(data.sliderItems)` to assign your data to `slideIndx`. Finally, in your jsx return you should use `slideIndx.map`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried these methods to no avail, my new error message shows that when I console.log(data.sliderItems) in the second .then() it shows up as undefined

Comment: Your json is probably different than what you posted here then. If you do just console.log(data) or enter http://localhost:3000/sliderItems on your browser what shows up?

Comment: when I console.log(data) it returns an array of my 3 objects

localhost:3000/sliderItems shows me the JSON data as an array of 3 objects as well

Comment: ok then, so your actual json doesn't have the brackets around it that you included in your post. That means you should use `setSlideIndx(data)` instead of `setSlideIndx(data.sliderItems)`

Comment: I wound up changing it back to setSlideIndx(data) I suppose while you were typing and it worked!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and patience lol. I will give you my upvote :)

Comment: So my data.json file actually does have the object curly bracket outside of the array but when I searched the localhost it only showed the array. Strange, sorry for the mix up

Comment: remember to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your issue